# Problem adding apps from SharePoint store SharePoint 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am running into a strange problem with my SharePoint online developer site.  I was able to successfully add the NAPA development tools app to the site with no issue.

But I want to add a few other apps to a team site on the same instance and I am getting caught in a never ending loop of Verifying that I actually want to add the app.

I using the following procedure.

Site Settings
Add an App
SharePoint Store
Choose the App
Click "Add it" - At this point I am brought to the "Confirm you wish to add the App" page.
I click Continue which appears to do the redirect correctly.
Click "Add it" - And I am brought back to "Confirm you wish to add the app" page.

At this point it is an infinite loop.

I have tried "More Actions" but "Request a License" is grayed out.

I feel like I am missing something.

Can anyone provide some guidance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the situation by only enabling the cookies in the internet browser, and later login to microsoft account. In my case I logined in as REDACTED@REDACTED.com. Later in the same browser, <kbd>Add It</kbd> for your app.